# Add one Office Document to another and keep format (Excel into Word) (OpenXmlPowerTools)

Tags: c#, excel, ms-word, ms-office, openxml

I want to add one office document to another. Until now I had to add a word document to another word document. This was very easy to implement via OpenXmlPowerTools.
But now I have to add a xls document into this word document. What can I do?

Important is to keep the xls style.

```
List<Source> sources = new List<Source>()
{
    new Source(new WmlDocument(source1), true),
    new Source(new WmlDocument(source2), false),
};

DocumentBuilder.BuildDocument(sources, pathDoc);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think here's your answer: "[Programmatically embedding an Excel spreadsheet into a Word document](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xunFeqCW2GA), Learn how to leverage the Open XML SDK to programmatically embed an Excel spreadsheet into a Word document"

Comment: but this is not dynamic, or? I understand this tutorial as a one time reflactoring of an excel doc?!? My Excel doc is dynamically.

Comment: okay i was wrong. it is dynamic but my file is every time destroyed. If I don't get it to run I will post the problem

Comment: Okay it works with one problem. There is no user which can double click its content. I want immediately the content without excel like borders

Comment: Maybe you can change the logic to trigger the loading without user, upon creation or so...